# passing parameters through loops

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am running a hive query and storing the result in the form of variable. then comparing the variable with other variable in if loops . now i want to parametrize the script to run the same if loop on 4 tables by passing the values. Below is the code.

Now the same if else loop i want to run for 4 tables
tbl1
tbl2
tbl3
tb4

I am new to scripting can anyone suggest how i can pass these table values one by one in the hive query through scripting over the same if loop instead of writing multiple if loops for different tables.

```
A1=$(hive -S -e "select max(date) from db.tbl1;")`
     if [[ "$A1" == "$CURRENT_dATE" ]]; then
ELSE [[ "$A1" != ""$CURRENT_dATE" ]] then
fi
```

Comment: In case you re-typed your code, please copy&paste it. Otherwise make sure you fix the syntax errors first. (Except if your question is about fixing these errors.) Is there anything else that must be changed for the other tables, e.g. variable names. Do you want something like `for table in tbl1 tbl2 tbl3 tbl4; do A1=$(hive -S -e "select max(date) from db.${table};"); if ... fi; done`? Please [edit] your question to answer.

Comment: @mohammedsiraj: This is not a (POSIX) shell script. You have a stray backquote. There is no `ELSE` in POSIX shell, nor a `[[`. Please fix your script first syntactically (by pasting it into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)), before posting it here.